# RDD partitioning in spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

The batches in spark streaming are the batches of RDD .Suppose batch of 3 RDDs.

Also spark documentation says that a block is created every 200ms by reciever , and partition is allotted to the block.

Say in 1 second I have batch of 3 RDDs , with 5 blocks if 200ms is considered.

So how will a RDD get partitioned across worker nodes , is the single RDD that will be partitioned or a complete batch.

I may have taken it in a wrong way . Please guide me

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One streaming batch corresponds to one RDD.  That RDD will have n partitions, where n = batch interval / block interval. 
Let's say you have the standard 200ms block interval and a batch interval of 2 seconds, then you will have 10 partitions.
Blocks are created by a receiver, and each receiver is allocated in a host. 
So, those 10 partitions are in a single node and are replicated to a second node.

When the RDD is submitted for processing, the hosts running the task will read the data from that host. Tasks executing on the same node will have "NODE_LOCAL" locality, while tasks executing on other nodes will have "ANY" locality and will take longer.

Therefore, to improve parallel processing, it's recommended to allocate several receivers and use union to create a single DStream for further processing. That way data will be consumed and processed by several nodes in parallel.

Comment: Thanks @maasg. Just to confirm that, if we have multiple receivers then we have multiple DStreams & each DStream corresponds to one RDD. So, when we union multiple Dstreams then we get a single DStream. This DStream consist of multiple RDD's or single RDD ?

Comment: @DineshSachdev108 Bu definition union() will "Return a new DStream that contains the union of the elements in the source DStream and otherDStream"

this means the result will be a dStream as well. And by definition a  "DStream is represented as a sequence of RDDs. 

Which means that the result will contain multiple RDDs depending on how many batches your receiver received.

Comment: @DineshSachdev108 that `DStream` will 'deliver' a single `RDD` at each interval of time. The `RDD` lineage will consist of the union of the `RDD`s of each participating `DStream`

Comment: @datmannz Thanks for bringing this comment-question to my attention. A DStream is represented as a sequence of RDDs *over time*. At a single point in time, it will contain only one `RDD`. In the case of union, that particular `RDD` will be the result of the union of underlying `RDD`s from the different participating `DStream`s .

Answer (score 3):

Is this still applicable in newer version of spark?

I read [an article](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/03/30/improvements-to-kafka-integration-of-spark-streaming.html) where the scenario with multiple receivers on spark is outdated and instead new direct kafka api (`createDirectStream`) would take care of pretty much everything for you.